# Finding $\frac{\cos(b)}{\cos(a)}$ given $\cos(x) e^{i y} = \frac{\sin(a)}{\sin(a+b)}$ and $-i \sin(x) e^{i y} = \frac{\sin(b)}{\sin(a+b)}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I have real $x$ and $y$, and I have the following implicit definitions of (complex) $a$ and $b$:

$$\cos(x) e^{i y} = \frac{\sin(a)}{\sin(a+b)}$$
$$-i \sin(x) e^{i y} = \frac{\sin(b)}{\sin(a+b)}$$

I want to re-express $\frac{\sin(b)}{\sin(a)}$ and $\frac{\cos(b)}{\cos(a)}$ in terms of just $x$ and $y$. The former is easy -- dividing the two implicit definitions gives

$$\frac{\sin(b)}{\sin(a)} = -i \tan(x)$$

while I'm currently stuck on finding $\frac{\cos(b)}{\cos(a)}$.

---

Is there a way in Mathematica to re-express $\frac{\sin(b)}{\sin(a)}$ and $\frac{\cos(b)}{\cos(a)}$ in terms of just $x$ and $y$?

In this particular case, it's difficult to solve the implicit definitions of $a,b$ explicitly in terms of $x,y$, but the simplicity of $\frac{\sin(b)}{\sin(a)}$ gives me hope that it can be done in Mathematica. I will accept any method that works for the above problem, but I would appreciate a comment on more generally re-expressing functions in terms of new coordinates when the coordinate change is only given implicitly.

---

For easier copy-paste, I've gathered some of the expressions below:

```
Cos[x] Exp[I y] = Sin[a]/Sin[a + b]

-I Sin[x] Exp[I y] = Sin[b]/Sin[a + b]

Sin[b]/Sin[a]

Cos[b]/Cos[a]
```

Comment: It would be useful to have these various inputs in Mathematica copy-pastable format.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Good idea, I've added in the key expressions in Mathematica copy-pastable format.

Comment: @user196574 the way is clear - expand the `Sin[a+b]`, take the `Cos[b]/Cos[a]` from `Sin[a+b]/Sin[a]` and `Sin[a+b]/Sin[b]` and so on with replacement of the `Sin[b]/Sin[a]` from your first solution..
The answer looks like a `Cos[b]/Cos[a]=0`, If I did not put mistakes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand  differences as exponentials and set numerators to zeros

```
cc = {(Cos[x] Exp[I y] - Sin[a]/Sin[a + b] // TrigToExp // Together //
  Numerator) == 0,
 (-I Sin[x] Exp[I y] - Sin[b]/Sin[a + b] // TrigToExp // Together // 
 Numerator) == 0}
```

$$ e^{2 i a+2 i b+2 i x+i y}-2 e^{2 i a+i b+i x}+e^{2 i a+2 i b+i y}+2 e^{i b+i x}-e^{2 i x+i y}-e^{i y}=0$$  $$-e^{2 i a+2 i b+2 i x+i y}-2 e^{i a+2 i b+i x}+e^{2 i a+2 i b+i y}+2 e^{i a+i x}+e^{2 i x+i y}-e^{i y}=0 $$

Expand integer multiples of exponents to powers of exponentials

```
       ccp = cc //. 
           {E^(a_ + b__) :> q[a] E^Plus[b], E^a_ :> q[a], 
              q[2 I a_] :> q[I a]^2}
```

$$q(i a)^2 q(i b)^2 q(i x)^2 q(i y)-2 q(i a)^2 q(i b) q(i x)+q(i a)^2 q(i b)^2 q(i y)+2 q(i b) q(i x)-q(i x)^2 q(i y)-q(i y)=0$$  $$-q(i a)^2 q(i b)^2 q(i x)^2 q(i y)-2 q(i a) q(i b)^2 q(i x)+q(i a)^2 q(i b)^2 q(i y)+2 q(i a) q(i x)+q(i x)^2 q(i y)-q(i y)=0$$

Solve for desired q's and restore exponentials

```
  Solve[ccp, {q[I a], q[I b]}][[-1]] /. {q[x_] :> E^x} // FullSimplify
```

$$e^{i a}\to \frac{e^{-i y} \left(i \sin (x+2 y)+\cos (x+2 y)+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{e^{2 i (x+y)} (\cos (2 y)-\cos (2 x))}-i \sin (x)-\cos (x)\right)}{-1+e^{2 i x}} $$
$$e^{i b}\to \frac{e^{-i y} \left(e^{i x} \left(1+e^{2 i y}\right)-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{e^{2 i (x+y)} (\cos (2 y)-\cos (2 x))}\right)}{1+e^{2 i x}}$$

that can be reduced (by hand, hopefully correct) to

$$e^{i a}\to \frac{e^{2 i y}+\sqrt{-e^{2 i x+2 i y}-e^{-2 \text{ix}+2 i y}+e^{4 i y}+1}-1}{e^{i x+i y}-e^{-\text{ix}+i y}}$$
$$e^{i b}\to \frac{e^{2 i y}-\sqrt{-e^{2 i x+2 i y}-e^{-2 \text{ix}+2 i y}+e^{4 i y}+1}+1}{e^{i x+i y}-e^{-\text{ix}+i y}}$$

Comment: This gives the nice compact result that $\frac{\cos(b)}{\cos(a)} = \cot(y) \tan(x)$.

Thanks for the systematic run-through. I learned a lot of good techniques in Mathematica! The $e^a \to q(a)$ trick seems like a good technique for solving transcendental equations.

Do you have a sense of whether this could be automated, like whether one could say "re-express $f(a,b)$ in terms of $x,y$ given these implicit relations for $a,b$ in terms of $x,y$?" I think maybe I'll ask that as a separate question. 

If you do Simplify instead of FullSimplify, you can do a little less work by hand.

Comment: Or maybe I should rephrase it -- do you have a sense of how to solve the problem in Mathematica if it weren't possible to explicitly solve $a,b$ in terms of $x,y$?

Comment: In the first place its a techique comparable to Fourier expansion (TrigReduce)  for harmonic forms that I used to switch off Mathematica's standard simplifcation technics for exponentials and trigs. The main strength of CAS's is polynomial algebra. The use of transcendentals obcsures these simple algorithims by the fact, that nobody dares to simplify log's without unreadable compex domain definitions.